# Relocating notification center pull down tab on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am making a game for IOS in landscape mode, the controls of the game require the user to slide their finger from the top of the screen to the bottom and vice versa if they choose. The problem is when you slide your finger from the top to the bottom of the screen the notification center tab comes down and since it's a fast paced game it's very likely that the user will end up pulling the notification center down often and unintentionally.

My solution to this problem is to redesign the game in portrait orientation and rebuild my game screens sideways, using SpriteBuilder and Cocos2d, so that the notification center would no longer interfere. However before I completely redo my almost completed game I would like to know if anybody has a more elegant solution to this problem, such as tricking the Notification Center in to positioning itself in it's normal portrait orientation location while still working in landscape mode using cocos2d? Thus allowing me not to have to completely redo my current screen layouts.

Comment: Any amount of "tricking" is not a good idea because that'll most likely not get you through approval.

Comment: Yes, that was a concern of mine too. I regret I didn't investigate this problem sooner.

Comment: If you hide status bar Notification window doesn't come immediately. You have to swipe again to get it.